# Translating data from one type to another in C++?

Tags: c++

I wanted to understand how type conversion happens in a professional grade software?
Consider the following conversions:

1. int to double
2. double to int
3. string to double
4. double to string

Currently I am using Qt for my project, which has API for doing these tasks.
So I just wanted to know how people perform these conversions with standard C++ only.
Accuracy, speed & memory are the priorities in their respective order.

Comment: with a static_cast where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is often implicit (since it's a promotion). The first and the second one [can be accomplished](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b103ee438696a3a) with a simple `static_cast`:

```
double x = 0.123;
int y = 123;
std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << '\n';
std::cout << static_cast<double>(y) << '\n';
```

The third one [would require](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3c55446bba3283) a `std::istringstream`:

```
std::string x = "123.456";
double y;
std::istringstream ss(x);
ss >> y;
```

The fourth [would require](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/167af47a92614630) a `std::stringstream`:

```
double x = 123.456;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << x;
ss.str(); // your string
```

Comment: I think 3 means something like `istringstream("123") s; s >> double_val;`

Comment: I do think the third one refers to the very specific case where the string is a representation of a double, i.e. "2.345"

Comment: Why the third one does not make any sense? There can be a string "14.3" which you may want to convert to a double.

Comment: @Jefffrey is std::stringstream a good option if a billion translations from double to string (or string to double) need to be performed?

Comment: @Cool_Coder, a good option on what basis?

Comment: @Jefffrey Likewise is static cast a good option if a billion translations from double to int need to be done?

Comment: In terms of 1. accuracy 2. speed 3. memory as preferences?
I was thinking that if we create our own functions for these translations then it would be more efficient. But I guess I was re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Cool_Coder, I doubt you can reinvent a more efficient `static_cast` since it is a language construct. I doubt the same of reinventing `std::istringstream` or `std::stringstream`. Chances are the standard library won't be the bottle-neck in your application. Don't pre-optimize.

Comment: :) Thank you for your highly useful insight!!!
Just a small querry, I hope that these classes are not affected if called simultaneously by multiple threads? I mean that internally if they are using some static variables, then multi threading will worsen the performance...

Comment: @Cool_Coder, I'm not sure about multithreading, but the standard library is pretty reliable and efficient for almost everything.

Comment: @Jefffrey I'd note that `boost::lexical_cast` tends to be faster than the stringstream versions.

Answer (score 2):

For int to double you can simply do `static_cast<double>(int_value);`
from double to int it depends on the case , most of the time static_cast would do , however, sometimes you need to have specific control over the value being rounded to int. For this you can use functions like `floor`, `round` , or `ceil`.

For string to anything and anything to string there are a couple of options:

`snprintf()` - not recommended unless you know what you are doing. accuracy is hard to control

`stringstream` / `istringstream` - this has good accuracy and easy to controll

`boost::format` - personal favorite, check doc: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

In terms of performance it depends i would pick snprintf to be the fastest in certain cases since it does not require allocations.

Answer (score 1):

1. **int to double** is a promotion in C++, which can be done implicitly.
2. **double to int** can also be done implicitly but it should be use with caution since many doubles either don't represent round integral values or are too big to be converted. Most compilers warn about that loss of precision, so the cast should be made explicit to get rid of the warning - *if* you are sure you are doing the right thing.
3. **string to double, double to string**: These are normally used only for input/output (GUI, console, textfiles, ...). Numerical values should be handled inside the program as such and not as strings. You should prevent double->string->double conversion chains inside your program when possible, since both conversions are not accurate and prone to rounding and other errors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that double-to-int is also implicit: `int main() { return 0.1; /* a little success */ }`

Comment: @Arne I agree that each translation will result in loss of data but there are cases for example, the GUI being a line edit by default gives the string form of input. Hence it should be converted to a double for performing calculations.

Comment: @Cool_Coder therefore I explicitly mentioned the GUI and other I/O. You should not do such translations *inside* the program, by which I mean e.g. between different modules.